# Selenium-Handling click on one time page of the webapplication

Tags: java, selenium

I have a webpage xyz.com, when I sign in on the webpage for the first time, I get a page which has a close button. Now, when user clicks on the close button on the page, the page vanishes and next time the user logs in then he won't be seeing this first time page.

In my selenium java code, I used xpath locator to identify and click on the close button when user logs in for the first time.

Now, in my code what condition do I need to put which will identify & click on the close button of this page if it gets the page or else it will skip the step and move on to the proceeding steps on the webpage.

Comment: what error do you get for the second time

Comment: You could wait for that specific element to appear for some moments using explicit wait condition. If your desired page/element appear then close it and proceed to next step.

Comment: Does the button have a name/ID which is unique? If so, try to check the page source and see if the element is present. You could do so by: string PageSource = Driver.PageSource;
            if (PageSource.Contains(expectedtext)) { Driver.FindElement(By.....).Click()}

Comment: the second time when the page is accessed i get an error "Webelement does not exist" this is a valid error because 2nd time when user is logged in he wont see the welcome screen close button since its the very first time process. Will the webdriverwait condition be useful in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to check if the element is shown on the page or not.

1.

```
try {
    webDriver.findElement(Locator locator).click();
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // move on
}
```

2.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
try {
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Locator locator);
    element.click();
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // move on
}
```

3.

```
List<WebElement> elements =  webDriver.findElements(Locator locator);
if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
    elements.get(0).click();
} else {
    // move on
    // maybe you don't need this else block
}
```

As you can see the first two possible implementations throw an unchecked exception. If you don't want these exceptions use the third one. I think it's a good practice to use the third implementation for normal behaviour when you just want to check if the element is there and you know it's okay.